# no compile error on a wrong type

Tags: typescript

Although defining a type of a function parameter the compiler doesn't give me a compile error when I pass in a wrong type.

```
class A
{
  constructor(public data: any)
  {}
};

class B extends A
{
  constructor(instance: A)
  {
    if (B.validate(instance.data))
      super(instance.data)
    else
      throw 'error';
  }

  static validate(instance: A): boolean
  {
    return typeof instance.data == 'number';
  }
}

let a = new A(null);
let b = new B(a);
```

The `if (B.validate(instance.data))` line is wrong and I would expect an compiler error but it compiles fine.

Comment: because 'data' is type 'any' and could be an instance of A that validate() function is expecting?

Comment: `instance.data` is of type `any`. `any` means: don't make any type checking: I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instance.data` is of type `any`, which is allowed to be passed where any type is expected.  You'll need to give it a more specific type if you want a compile error.

Comment: It looks like `any` works the opposite way I thought. `static validate(instance: A): boolean` requires type A so I would expect that anything more general would yield an error. What other type could be used instead of `any`?

Comment: You are looking for `{}` or `unknown`.  These are the most general types, while `any` is a special type that bypasses type checking.

Answer (score 1):

There's no error because `data` is declared as type `any`. Values of type `any` can be used anywhere without error, because that is the job of the `any` type.

Answer (score -1):

If the signature of `validate` is from a type **instance: A**, then, You can't pass `instance.data` to it, you should pass `instance` instead.

Comment: He/she can, and that's precisely what surprises him/her.